# Single word request for "first-person-ness"? Or "I-ness"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like a single word which mean "first-person-ness".

One stab at this is to say first person could be referred to as the *self* but then one bumps into taken words derived therefrom like the adjective *selfish* which is derogatory.  Also *self* can be used in contexts other than the first person, e,g, *himself*.

I want the word to be neither laudatory nor derogatory.

*Subject* maybe another possible lead: in the sentence *'I like you'* we have a transitive verb with a subject and an object, *I* and *you*.  But in the sentence *'He likes her'* the subject is no longer the first person, instead it is *he*, the third person.

*Self-subject* might be close but again doesn't rule out third person.

In terms of example use, consider a psycho-therapy session between a psychologist and a patient.  The psychologist asserts that the patient sees themself in a relation to a second person and that they are copying the attributes of that second person, which the patient then denies.  So, let's flesh out an example.  The psychologist observes that the patient is found to be regimented and disciplined but the psychologist suspects that this is performative and suggests that they aspire to be a soldier, to which the patient replies:

"Oh no, Doctor!  I AM a soldier!  I don't aspire to be a soldier; I AM a soldier!  I may not be enlisted but I'm as brave as any enlisted in any army!  I may not have a gun but I can shoot as well as any marksman!  I can march like a Roman and swim like a Marine!  I AM a soldier!"

In this quote, the patient is denying any relations to some putative second person, some other person, literally *an-other* person.  Instead, they are emphatically affirming that the said role, in this case soldier, is them, is truly them.  They are denying the *second-person-ness* and instead are positing a *first-person-ness*.

So actually, it looks like I also need a second single word request for *second-person-ness* but we can roll them into one question.

It's almost like I'm asking for *"I-ness"* [and perhaps also *"you-ness"* and *"he-ness"*]

P.S.  I hope this doesn't trip into Philosophy or Psychiatry.

Comment: You’ve provided context which is good, but we also need a sentence where you show how you’d use this word (put a blank where the word should go.)

Comment: I feel a little confused: the question seems straight-forward until the example, and then I think see a misapprehension about what 1st- 2nd- and 3rd-person mean. Freely admit it could be a fault of my interpretation.

Comment: Is is not ego you seek?

Comment: See also _soul, personality, atman, selfhood, ego, mind, consciousness,_ and other, similar, words. The first person is the speaker, and the speaker is sposta express the Inner Whatever.

Comment: I think "quiddity" does capture some of what you're trying to express, but it may be too general.

Comment: If the person does see himself as a soldier, the entire exercise makes little sense. "first-person-ness" is usually called **selfhood**. The patient is not denying the "other person". They are saying they are what the "therapist" is calling a soldier. Anyway, all this is a very bad therapeutic tactic. The patient has to come up with the idea of soldier, not the therapist, who by doing so is projecting onto the patient.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the lack of an example sentence will lead to guesses and opinions.

Comment: I suggest phrasing the question more concisely.

Answer (score 0):

Funnily, *OED* lists *me-ness* with the meaning and the earliest citation as below:

> The fact or consciousness of one's identity as a unique individual.
>
> 1906   in *N.E.D.* at *-ness*   This is also the case with formations on pronouns, adverbs, etc., as I-ness, me-ness, whatness [etc.].

Thus, the word *I-ness* is listed in *OED* also and it is same as the earlier *I-hood* with the meaning:

> *Metaphysics*
> Conscious personality.

Although, *OED* lists them as frequency band 1 which puts them among the rarest words. If you want something more common but possibly less precise, there is *self-identity*. *Selfness* comes to mind but it can mean selfishness.

Answer (score 0):

Selfhood. The state of being oneself.

You can't say self-ness in English. And if you did, it wouldn't have a connotation of 'selfish', that's another thing.

But you can use 'selfhood' to describe the state of being oneself.

So in your example, it could be 'the patient's perception of selfhood was that he was actually a soldier'.